# How can I read and run Prolog code in Java with a simple engine?

Tags: java, prolog

I want to run Prolog code using Java. 
I found some engines, but the only one that seemed easly to use was [w-prolog](http://waitaki.otago.ac.nz/~michael/wp/) . However, when I tried to use it I figured out he doesn't support simple things like Lists or dynamic assertions.

I also saw [tuprolog](http://alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/) but it seemed far more heavy than I wanted and it seemed I need to recreate all my code in a Java syntax (separating terms, facts, etc).

I just want to run prolog from a file and read the result in Java.

Anyone knows how can I do it? Does tuprolog allows me to do it in a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [Jekejeke Prolog](http://www.jekejeke.ch/) can do that. It's a 100% java written Prolog. Though, being a commercial solution, it may not be a fit for you.

Comment: I managed to work with it. However, I can't find a way to use asserts (the engine says that asserts do not exist).

Comment: Ok, found out that assert is depecrated and assertz works. Only have a small problem with the ouput returned, but I guess I can work with that. Thanks :).

Comment: @Tiago Almeida: In ISO Prolog, there is `asserta/1` and `assertz/1`. There is no `assert/1`. Systems differed a lot in what they did for `assert/1`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option - particularly interesting for Asian countries might be [Minerva](http://www.ifcomputer.com/MINERVA/).

Answer (score 2):

[SWI-Prolog JPL](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/) is a bi-directional Java/Prolog interface which works quite well. I've used this quite a bit (mainly calling Prolog from Java, but also the other way around) and the performance seems fairly good.

Answer (score 0):

you can also take a look at my old project PROL http://igormaznitsa.com/projects/prol/index.html but it is not an opensource one yet